# [org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@f76d0bdd -> unknown locator]

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read the element so that i can later use to get the id of that element. Using below code to get first the WebElement. But throws the following in console:

"[org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@f76d0bdd -> unknown locator]"

```
WebElement ele = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
System.out.println("webelement is :"+ele);
```

Comment: What line does occur on?

Comment: The print statement.. The exact error i have put here as title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this because you are asking the code to essentially print `ele.toString()`.

Which, according to the source, is going to give the exact message you see:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.java#375

Specifically:

```
public String toString() {
    if (foundBy == null) {
      return String.format("[%s -> unknown locator]", super.toString());
    }
    return String.format("[%s]", foundBy);
}
```

It says 'unknown locator' because one isn't explicitly set by `setFoundBy`.

So, I would suggest that if you want the ID of the element, you use:

```
ele.getAttribute("id");
```

Comment: Please show us the HTML of the element you are targetting this against.

Comment: `<input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Show alert box" autofocus />`

Comment: Well it doesn't have an ID at all, so what are you trying to get? What *exact* details of the element are you trying to print?